# jquery: detecting changes in dynamically generated input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My working code dynamically generates a series of input fields. Each row of fields belongs to one database record and I use php's dynamic array notation ('[]') to capture the values. All good so far...

Now I want to check which, if any, of the fields the user has changed.

I've explored several approaches and I'm open to any an all, but I'm trying to work with the jQuery/html5 input event. All of the examples I've been able to find reference the *id* of the element which might be changed, but since I can't (easily) generate unique id's for each input in the array, I'm at a loss as to how to detect change.  Once I get change detection working, I need a way to grab and include the ID of the changed elements in my `$_POST` data.

The basic form structure looks like this:

```
<form>
    <?php foreach($queryresults as $row) { ?>
        <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="r_date[]" value ="<?php echo $queryresults[$row]['date']; ?>" >
        <input type="text" name="r_note[]" value ="<?php echo $queryresults[$row]['note']; ?>" >
        <input type="hidden" name="r_id[]" value ="<?php echo $queryresults[$row]['id']; ?>" > //used in the form handling
    <?php } ?>
        </div>
    //the following is not in production, just used to test jquery code
    <input type="text" id="testcase" value ="change this to test jquery"> 
</form>
```

This jQuery works for testcase (only!) (Credit for the above code:

1. this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2qsa/2/)
2. this [blog post](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript)

```
<script>
$( document ).on('input','#testcase',function() {
if (e.originalEvent.propertyName == "value") {
        console.log("Value changed! - propertychange");
    }
});

$( document ).on("input", "#testcase", function() {
    if (!propertyChangeUnbound) {
        $("#testcase").unbind("propertychange");
        propertyChangeUnbound = true;
    }
    console.log("Value changed! - input");
});
</script>
```

I've tried adding a class to each of the input elements and replacing `#testcase` with the classname in the jQuery, but that produces no output.

Comment: While there is most likely a jQuery solution this kind of use case benefits greatly from an observable view model. Take a look at Angular and/or Knockout.

Comment: Just a quick question, can anything other than the value be changed, and  does the `input` event fire on anything other than the value changing, and if so, what property would that be ?

Comment: @SpencerRuport will check those out.  Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo I'm not sure I know how to answer your question.  My understanding is that the value attribute of the input element is what is changed by user edits. Tell me more about what you're thinking.

Comment: I was just wondering what the heck you are doing, why would you have to check if the value was changed, there's not much else it could be, at least I can't think of anything else that would change and trigger an `input` event? You know that if you use names instead of ID's they are included when submitting the form, even if you use jQuery's serialize() ?

Comment: Maybe something like this will help -> http://jsfiddle.net/yDq3e/

Comment: @adeneo - fair question.  On one page there might be 15-20 rows, so if the user only changes one of the rows, I was trying to save the overhead of writing a bunch of records back to the db that didn't need to be updated. As for names vs. IDs...that's what I'm using. I don't have any problem getting data submitted properly.  I'm just trying to see which of the 20 rows being submitted needs updating.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  I've tried it, but the first part isn't capturing the change.  I added an alert (before the changed = ... code) and it's not popping up and there are no errors in my firebug console.  When does the input event fire?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the best way for you to do this may be something like this:

(Also, FYI, you forgot your PHP tags inside your HTML tag to echo out the data.)

```
<input type="text" name="r_date[]" value ="<?php echo $queryresults[$row]['date']; ?>" data-orig ="<?php echo $queryresults[$row]['date']; ?>">
```

Now you'll have the original/unchanged data as an attribute called `data-orig`, which would be accessed like `$('#elem').attr('data-orig')`, that you can use to compare against it's current value, which you can retrieve using `$('#elem').val()`.

This is also a good way to do it because if they change the value, but then change it back to the original value, it won't be marked as changed. So if they change a field, then press Ctrl+Z in their browser to undo it, it won't be marked as changed in your app.

Here is a simple example with JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97A6x/ which shows binding the change events and detecting the change using jQuery.

Comment: This is awesome and yes you understood correctly. I've fixed the php tagging...good catch. Now, the last mile. What I'd like to do is modify your fiddle concept a bit and insert a 'data-status="changed"' attribute into the field that was changed. But then I need a way to either: a) only transmit status=changed fields or b) pass the data-status attribute (and db identifier) to my php form handler. ...or maybe there's a better way to handle this? Thoughts?